# MATLAB: Getting error message while using try/catch

Tags: matlab, error-handling, camera, try-catch, snapshot

That's why I coded a wrapper-function which tries to handle the error so that in case of a dropped frame, it simply get's captured again and doesn't abort the running code:

```
function img = getsnapshotfcn(obj, maxRetries, pausing)
    % Default args
    if(nargin < 3)
        pausing = 4; % in sec
    end
    if(nargin < 2)
        maxRetries = 20;
    end

    % Try to capture snapshot...
    i = 0;
    while(1)
        i = i+1;
        try
            img = getsnapshot(obj);

            % success? -> break loop
            break;
        catch err
            % Pause shortly before retry
            pause(pausing);
        end

        % maxRetries reached? -> error
        if(i > maxRetries)
            error('snapshot:maxRetriesReached', 'blaaa...');
        end
    end
end
```

When now using `getsnapshotfcn()` I'm sometimes still still getting the above posted error message shown in the console and I'm wondering why. I didn't expect the error to disappear (and please don't help me about this, I already know that I need to set the `PacketDelay` which I already did but in rare occasions it still happens even though running on a fast CPU) but I expected it to NOT being displayed as I expected it to simply be catched via `try-catch`.

What could be the case it's still being shown in the console?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: My guess is that the error does not arise in Matlab, but the message is printed to the console by some external tool (called via `system()` or a mex file maybe). What is `getsnapshot()`, where did you get it, can you modify it? Can you maybe detect that an error happened by a special return value given by that function?

Comment: Good approach/point, but can't imagine that's the problem as `getsnapshot()` is a built-in function in MATLAB http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/imaq/getsnapshot.html. There are neither external scripts nor mex-files involved. I simply let run a script with a while loop which captures several frames with the wrapper `getsnapshotfcn()` to avoid script abortion. Nothing different involved. AND FYI: this is an error I'm already observed several times before and it's described on the mathworks homepage thus it clearly is a MATLAB error :-) Any other idea still? :)

Comment: And I thought I had access to all the toolboxes! :-) Is it new? I've heard about other new functionality in 2013b to be a bit buggy. No, no other ideas.

Comment: It's there since R2012b :-) http://www.mathworks.de/help/releases/R2012b/imaq/getsnapshot.html?searchHighlight=getsnapshot. But still thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by using `evalc` in MATLAB using

```
evalc('img = getsnapshot(obj);')
```

instead of

```
img = getsnapshot(obj);
```

in the above code :-)